# No tools available from pyOCR

Tags: python, ocr

It seems that I have not installed pyOCR correctly cause I am get an empty list when I do:

```
import pyocr.builders
pyocr.get_available_tools()
```

Any ideas?

I have installed pyOCR in an environment through pip:

```
pip install pyocr --upgrade
```

**EDIT**

The following did the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-ell
```

Comment: In windows system just add the path to the tesseract directory to the system path environment variable. It'll work then.

Comment: @user706838 i have installed pyocr package still im getting this error import pyocr.builders
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyocr.builders'
im using ubuntu. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

pyocr requires any ocr engine/tools associated with it. You are expected to install any ocr engine/tool seperately like Tesseract-OCR or any other. After installing the tool independently, point the PATH variable into the corresponding directory so that pyocr can locate the tool.